# Cannot resolve symbol 'minecraft' - minecraft forge 1.8.9 modding

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge, unresolved-external

I was trying to make a 1.8.9 mod for minecraft forge.
I was using the Intellij IDEA for coding, i use the most recent version.
In the mod i am using Gradle v 4.9 and FrogeGradle 2.1-SNAPSHOT.
Also i use Java v8.

When trying to `import net.minecraft.xxx...` i get the '`Cannot resolve symbol 'minecraft'`'

Several people across the forums had same or similar error (especially with early versions of minecraft), but almost none had answers, those who had, didnt really do anything.

[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tyKI.png)

Tried changing java version (switched from 17 to 8)
Tried chanching gradle version (2.7 -> 4.9, since 2.7 was "not supported")
Also tried changind ForgeGradle version (I left it as 2.1-SNAPSHOT as it was in the original mdk file)
Searching across other forums & searching for help in dc
Tried several commands that people recommended in those forums, but they didnt fix the issue.

Comment: This looks like Java, which is not JavaScript (see http://javascriptisnotjava.com/). Can you please verify this and update your tags to reflect?

Comment: You need to have the minecraft client sources / forge API as a dependency to your mod.